# Ненормативная лексика, вопрос о мастурбации

Tags: выбор-слов, значение-слов, обсценная-лексика

Корректно ли употреблять глагол «дрочить» в отношении женской мастурбации?

Comment: Наконец-то интересные вопросы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А словари говорят, что дрочить = мастурбировать. И ни слова о ненормативности.

[ДРОЧИТЬ](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ruwiki/907411/%D0%94%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C):

> **Мастурба́ция** (лат. manus—рука + stupro—осквернять) — форма удовлетворения индивидом полового влечения путём раздражения
>   собственных эрогенных зон или эрогенных зон партнёра (так называемая
>   взаимная мастурбация, при которой партнёры стимулируют друг друга —
>   петтинг). В научно-популярной литературе и публицистике также
>   встречаются названия: онани́зм, по имени персонажа Ветхого Завета
>   Онана, или рукоблу́дие.

У Ефремовой дрочить - нежить, холить.

Вполне годится.

[Смотреть, что такое "Дрочить" в других словарях...](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/160970/%D0%94%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C)

Comment: «Онанизм есть случка самим с собою, через мерзкое возбуждение своих мужских или женских блудливых органов с помощью рук или другого барахла»…

Comment: В дополнение к разным значениям, упомянутым в словарях.  Если не ошибаюсь, в одном из рассказов Марии Семёновой был персонаж, которого называли "дрочилой". Оказалось, это человек, занимающийся дрочением - пошивом изделий из толстой кожи и/или грубой ткани. До нашего времени дошло, очевидно, однокоренное слово "дратва" - очень толстая и прочная нитка.